# Check if user confirmed during login, using devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, devise-confirmable

I have a React FE + Rails BE app and I'm using devise for authentication. I'm trying to generate a custom error message for users who try to log in after their confirmation period has expired.

Currently, they are being blocked from logging in but it doesn't show a custom error message explaining why they have been blocked.

My `session_controller.rb`

```
def create

  if BANNED_EMAILS.include?(params["user"]["email"])
    render :status => 500, :json => { error: true, message: 'Your account has been suspended. Please contact us for more information.' }

//I get an error `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find User)` when I try this even though the user has already signed up and exists in the database

  elsif User.find_by_email!(params[:user][:email]).confirmed? == true
    render :json => { error: true, message: 'Please confirm your registered email to access your account.'}, :status => 500
  else
    self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    render :status => 200, :json => resource.to_json    
end
```

end

Is there some other way to pull the information of the user trying to log in or is there some other way to show the same error?

Comment: You can use `where` caluse with both emails downcased/upcased

Comment: @Ruslan how exactly should I write the emails in the where clause? I tried `where` but maybe I didn't pass the attributes properly

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: @Ruslan PostgreSQL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at `Devise::SessionsController` (or any of the devise controllers) you can see that it yields:

```
class Devise::SessionsController < DeviseController
  # POST /resource/sign_in
  def create
    self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    set_flash_message!(:notice, :signed_in)
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    yield resource if block_given?
    respond_with resource, location: after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  end
end
```

This lets subclasses tap into the flow without overriding the entire method.

```
class MySessionsController < DeviseController
  def create
    # taps into the yield right after the user is authenticated by warden
    super do |user|
      if user.banned?
        # 500 is the wrong response code
        # it means that the server is broken and cannot respond to the request
        render json: { error: true, message: 'Your account has been suspended. Please contact us for more information.' }, 
          status: 401 and return
      elsif user.requires_confirmation?
        render json: { error: true, message: 'Please confirm your registered email to access your account.'}, 
          status: 401 and return
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Instead of using a code constant (are you really going to redeploy the application every time a user gets banned?) you should use a flag on the user's table to denote if the user is banned.

Likewise, the business logic of determining when a user must be confirmed should be handled on the model layer:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
  def requires_confirmation?
    if user.confirmed? || user.created_at < 3.days.ago
      false
    else
      true
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: on `sign_in(resource_name, resource)` site is redirecting to `:new` after `401(unauthorized)`. so `yield resource if block_given?` is not yielded...

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Will try to find the user by email, not case sensitive.

`user = User.where("upper(email) = '?'", params[:user][:email].upcase).first`

then you can try `user.confirmed?` if `user` is not `nil`